# Error in Using SendGrid Module for Contact Form in React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, module, sendgrid

I am trying to implement a contact form in my React website using the SendGrid module for email sending. I have server-side code in a file called server.js and client-side code in card.tsx. When I run npm start, I encounter an error related to the fs and path modules in the SendGrid package. Additionally, I have an issue with the type checking in my Contact.tsx file. How can I resolve these errors and make the contact form work properly?

Here is my server-side code in server.js:

```
// server.js
const express = require("express");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { resolve } = require("path-browserify");

// Set up SendGrid API key
sgMail.setApiKey("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");

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, server!");
});

// Route to handle sending emails
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  const { Name, Email, Message, submitbutton } = req.body;

  const msg = {
    to: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
    from: "gdscusyd@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example Subject",
    text: `Name: ${Name}\nEmail: ${Email}\nMessage: ${Message}\nSubmit Button: ${submitbutton}`,
    html: `<p>Name: ${Name}</p><p>Email: ${Email}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p><p>Submit Button: ${submitbutton}</p>`,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.toString());
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});

// Set up fallback for path module
resolve.fallback = { path: require.resolve("path-browserify") };

// Start the server
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Here's code for my client-side code in card.tsx (code for contact form):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import cardcss from "./Card.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

interface CardProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

function Card(props: CardProps) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const nameInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const messageInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (messageInputRef.current) {
      messageInputRef.current.focus();
      messageInputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

      // Delay setting the cursor position
      setTimeout(() => {
        messageInputRef.current?.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
      }, 0);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleFocus = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      nameInputRef.current &&
      emailInputRef.current &&
      messageInputRef.current
    ) {
      const nameInput = nameInputRef.current.value;
      const emailInput = emailInputRef.current.value;
      const messageInput = messageInputRef.current.value;

      const contactData = {
        Name: nameInput,
        Email: emailInput,
        Message: messageInput,
      };

      axios
        .post("/send-email", contactData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          // Handle success response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          // Handle error response
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={cardcss.cardcontainer}>
      <div className={cardcss.imagecontainer}>
        <img src={props.imageUrl} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardtitle}>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardbody}>
        <p>{props.body}</p>

        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div>
            <label className={cardcss.namelabel} htmlFor="name">
              Name:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.nameinput}
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              ref={nameInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.emailcontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.emaillabel} htmlFor="email">
              Email:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.emailinput}
              type="text"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              ref={emailInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.messagecontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.messagelabel} htmlFor="message">
              Message:
            </label>
            <input
              ref={messageInputRef}
              className={cardcss.messageinput}
              type="text"
              id="message"
              name="message"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              onFocus={handleFocus}
            />

            <button className={cardcss.sendbutton} type="submit">
              Send
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

and here is for my contact page code:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import contactcss from "./Contact.module.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Card from "../../components/ui/Card";
import {
  faInstagram,
  faFacebook,
  faLinkedin,
  faDiscord,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import emaillogo from "../../resources/email-logo.png";
import { setApiKey, send } from "@sendgrid/mail";

const Contact: React.FC = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
      inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }
  };

  setApiKey(
    "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"
  ); 

  function submitFormHandler(contactData: {
    Name: string;
    Email: string;
    Message: string;
  }) {
    const { Name, Email, Message } = contactData;

    const msg = {
      to: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
      from: Email,
      subject: "GDSC Contact Form - New Message",
      text: `Message from: ${Name}\nMessage: ${Message}`,
      html: `<p>Message from: ${Name}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p>`,
    };

    send(msg)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Email sent successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.toString());
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={contactcss.background}>
          <img
            className={contactcss.emaillogo}
            src={emaillogo}
            alt="Contact Us"
          />
          <div className={contactcss.contact}>Contact Us</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Card
        title="We're keen to hear from you!"
        imageUrl="https://images.app.goo.gl/D6m6hHMnP1gjsKKV7"
        body=""
        onSubmitForm={submitFormHandler}
      />

      <div className={contactcss.whitebackground}>
        <div className={contactcss.socials}>
          <h1>Follow Our Socials</h1>
          <p className={contactcss.socialmedia}>
            Stay connected with GDSC USYD by following us on our social media
            channels:
          </p>
          <div>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gdscusyd/">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.instagram}
                icon={faInstagram}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gdsc.usyd">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.facebook}
                icon={faFacebook}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://discord.com/channels/872033047652990986/872033047652990989">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.discord}
                icon={faDiscord}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/gdsc-usyd/">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.linkedin}
                icon={faLinkedin}
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Error Messages:

Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/parisvinuya/RARYA - GDSC WEBSITE/gdsc-website/main/node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes'

I am wondering how I can get this contact form to work? I've already separated server-side code and client-side code but the site is still not running...Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should not implement the SendGrid API on the client side (React).
Your contact form should contain logic to send form data to the back-end and have the back-end implement the logic for sending the email.

With that out of the way, you are using the same package on the client and server side of the application. As I stated in the previous paragraph, you shouldn't implement email logic on the client side. Saving and sending your API key on the client side is not safe nor responsible as it can be stolen easily.

The reason your facing `fs` error while compiling the client side code is that the client side (browser run JavaScript) does not contain the `fs` module. `fs` module stands for filesystem and is only implemented in NodeJS that runs on the operating system.

To fix this issue, remove all logic related to SendGrid from the client-side and have your server side API receive the form inputs and send the required message to the user.

In other words, Contact Component:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import contactcss from "./Contact.module.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Card from "../../components/ui/Card";
import {
  faInstagram,
  faFacebook,
  faLinkedin,
  faDiscord,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import emaillogo from "../../resources/email-logo.png";
// import { setApiKey, send } from "@sendgrid/mail"; // This should be removed

const Contact: React.FC = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
      inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }
  };

  const handleSendMessageToApi => async (data: any) => {
    const response = await fetch(YOUR_API_URI, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    return await response.json();
  }
/* This should be removed
  setApiKey(
    "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"
  ); 
*/ 
  function submitFormHandler(contactData: {
    Name: string;
    Email: string;
    Message: string;
  }) {
    const { Name, Email, Message } = contactData;
    
    /* This should be removed
    const msg = {
      to: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
      from: Email,
      subject: "GDSC Contact Form - New Message",
      text: `Message from: ${Name}\nMessage: ${Message}`,
      html: `<p>Message from: ${Name}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p>`,
    }; 

    send(msg)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Email sent successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.toString());
      }); */
      
      // Replace code above with your own implementation as below.
      // Your implementation might differ, make changes based on your use case.
      handleSendMessageToApi(contactData)
        .then((apiResponse) => console.log(apiResponse))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={contactcss.background}>
          <img
            className={contactcss.emaillogo}
            src={emaillogo}
            alt="Contact Us"
          />
          <div className={contactcss.contact}>Contact Us</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Card
        title="We're keen to hear from you!"
        imageUrl="https://images.app.goo.gl/D6m6hHMnP1gjsKKV7"
        body=""
        onSubmitForm={submitFormHandler}
      />

      <div className={contactcss.whitebackground}>
        <div className={contactcss.socials}>
          <h1>Follow Our Socials</h1>
          <p className={contactcss.socialmedia}>
            Stay connected with GDSC USYD by following us on our social media
            channels:
          </p>
          <div>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gdscusyd/">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.instagram}
                icon={faInstagram}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gdsc.usyd">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.facebook}
                icon={faFacebook}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://discord.com/channels/872033047652990986/872033047652990989">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.discord}
                icon={faDiscord}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/gdsc-usyd/">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.linkedin}
                icon={faLinkedin}
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

With the changes above, you should refactor your server-side code to receive the data and send the user an email using the SendGrid API. I haven't looked at the back-end code; so make changes accordingly.

Hope this answer was useful.